# How to iterate over li elements using firefox selenuim ide commands?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

So i have a `ul` list with `li` elements,  I'm using:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//tr[@id='regularprice_savings']/td[2]</td>
    <td>temp</td>
</tr>
```

than i can use echo command to print / do what ever i want with it, as well when convert it to code i can use these variables

Is there any command which converted do `findElements` while exporting it to a `junit` tests? and getting all of the `li` elements in and store them as list?